# Arduino sensing its 'Motion'

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am working on a project where I need the Arduino to 'sense' at what direction its moving. For example, I want the Arduino to 'sense' that it
is moving towards 'forward' direction, 'backwards' direction etc.

Is that possible using an Arduino? Can I use a motion sensor to do this (probably not)?

Can any one please help me to find the right 'direction'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need a acceleration/gyro sensor, like the MPU6050.

By tracking x/y/z movements, you can define what is forward/backards etc. Also you can track angles/tilts (in 3 directions).

See an example how to use it here: [MPU-6050](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050)

Comment: Thank you, I don't wanna go deep here, but is there a library present which I could use to make my work easier?

Comment: You can change the example as library, or maybe this link helps: https://maker.pro/arduino/tutorial/how-to-interface-arduino-and-the-mpu-6050-sensor

I never tried the MPU6050 myself.

Comment: Well I tried by borrowing one from a friend, it worked  thanks